# How do I write a balanced redox reaction for the oxidation of chalcocite [(Cu2S) (s)] by O2 (g) to form Cu2+ (aq) and SO42- (aq)

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I'm not exactly sure how to get the oxidation and reduction half reactions. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what is the oxidation states of Cu and S in the reagents?

Comment: Apparently I'm supposed to arrive at this answer: Cu2S +5/2O2 +(2H+) gives 2Cu2+ + SO4^2- +H2O

Comment: I'm just not sure how to write the reduction and oxidation half reactions to arrive at the above given answer. Its a question from the book ''Soil and water chemistry'' by Michael Essington

Answer (score 1):

I think that the half-reaction method for this reaction would look something like this:

- $\ce{Cu2S + O2 + H2SO4 -> CuSO4 + H2O}$

---

- $\ce{2Cu^+ -2e^- -> 2Cu^2+}$ (*oxidation*)
- $\ce{S^2- + 4H2O - 8e^- -> SO4^- + 8H^+}$ (*oxidation*)
- $\ce{O2 + 4H^+ +4e^- -> 2H2O}$ (*reduction*)

---

- $\ce{2Cu2S + 5O2 + 2H2SO4 -> 4CuSO4 + 2H2O}$

Answer (score 0):

I think  that the following method would look parallel to the method  mentioned in the above post:

- $\ce{4H2O + Cu2S + H2SO4 -> 2CuSO4 + 10H+ + 10e^- }$ (*oxidation*)
- $5(\ce{Cu2S + 3O2 + H2SO4 + 2H+ + 2e^- ->2CuSO4 +  2H2O})$ (*reduction*)

---

- $\ce{6Cu2S + 15O2 + 6H2SO4 -> 12CuSO4 + 6H2O}$
- $\ce{2Cu2S + 5O2 + 2H2SO4 -> 4CuSO4 + 2H2O}$